# Weird IE7 Problem

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7, overflow

Page located [here](http://joecoledesign.com/portfolio).

In IE7, everything works perfectly until you slect one of the "filters" (e.g. Other). After this, the pop up bubble (span.info) no longer is on top when it is animated to above the image.

There is no overflow:hidden on the li or anything like that, and applying a z-index to the span.info made no difference.

You can tell that the span.info is still working somewhat properly because you can just barely see the bottom of it and then it gets cut off.

This seems like an overflow problem, but I can find no trace of anything like that looking at the developer tools (using IE8 in compatibility mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I just decided to go with a completely different solution than what I had. It had nothing to do with opacity or z-index (afaik)... it looked like the overflow was cutting it off, but I had specifically set it to visible.

Ah well, another great idea shot because of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is an opacity problem? It may have nothing to do with the z-index?